# Multithreading Reuse with Objects in While loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to multithreading and already started experiencing problems.
I would like to implement a 10 threads reuse on a Class' Function, whose Parent Class has 4 functions inside a while loop, but it gives me errors like ***"error C3867: 'std::thread::join': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"***  and "std::system_error at memory location"
Since I don't know how well I explained it, I will show you pseudocode of what I would like to implement:
Main.cpp

```
Game newGame;
/* Create Players */
Population pop(NumberOfPlayers);

/* Create Enemies */
std::vector<Enemies> enemy;
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEnemies; i++) {
    Enemies e(i);
    enemy.push_back(e);
}
while (!pop.hasFinished) {
        std::thread threads[NUM_THREADS];
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            threads[i] = std::thread(std::bind(&Population::populationMove, &pop, (i * NumberOfPlayers / NUM_THREADS)));
            //std::cerr << "In Thread " << i << "\n";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
            if(threads[i].joinable)
                threads[i].join;
            //std::cerr << "In Thread " << i << "\n";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEnemies; i++) {
            enemy[i].movement();
            enemy[i].checkIfKills();
        }
        enemymoves++;
        if (pop.checkIfAllDead()) {
            pop.calculateBest();
            pop.createNewPopulation();
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfEnemies; i++) {
                if ((pop.gen - 1) % 5 == 0) {
                    enemy[i].save();
                }
                enemy[i].reset();
            }
        }
}
```

This is the pseudocode for populationMove()

```
 Population::populationMove(int threadStartIndex) {

    for (int i = threadStartIndex; i < threadStartIndex + (player.size() / NUM_THREADS); i++) {
        mtx.lock();
        player[i].move();
        mtx.unlock();

    }
```

Comment: Maybe try putting `std::thread threads[N_THREADS];` inside the while loop instead of outside?

Comment: When asking about build errors or message, please include an actual [mcve] that we can use to replicate the errors. And always include the actual error messages from that example, copy-pasted in full and complete (and copy-pasted as text, not images). And add comments in the code to show where the errors are. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "error C3867: 'std::thread::join': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

Comment: There's a typo, to begin with: `= std::thread(&Class::classFunction, &classObject, threadindex);` -- no braces should be there.

Comment: First of all copy-paste the ***full*** and ***complete*** error output, into the *question itself*. Then show the actual code causing the error, which you don't.

Comment: @vikAy -- Every C++ compiler error can be reproduced with a full example.  There is no need to post code as a jigsaw puzzle we need to put together.  To add, it doesn't matter what `classfunction` does -- the error is a *compiler* error, not a runtime error.  This means that the function could be empty, as what the function is doing has no bearing whatsoever on the compilation.  [This is what you should have posted](https://rextester.com/KVLY20494)

Comment: Added my actual while loop and function.

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but you don't need `std::bind`. More related to your error (now that we can see the actual code) you don't *call* `join`. Neither do you call `joinable`.

Comment: FYI: This is bad: `for (...) { mtx.lock(); ... mtx.unlock(); }`. _All_ of the work that each thread does is happening with the mutex locked. Only one thread at a time can lock the mutex, so that means, only one thread at a time can do any work. There is no benefit from using threads if you don't let them work _concurrently_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think this is your first problem.

```
std::thread threads[N_THREADS]; // array of threads
```

This will construct 10 threads, not SPACE for 10 threads. I wasn't absolutely positive, so I tested this way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { cout << "Foo constructor.\n"; }
};

int main(int, char **) {
    cout << "Allocate array.\n";

    Foo array[10];

    cout << "Loop.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        array[i] = Foo();
    }

    cout << "Done.\n";
}
```

This displayed the output from my first prompt, then 10 "Foo constructor" messages, then my second "Loop" prompt, then 10 more "Foo constructor" messages.

I think you probably need to make that an array of thread pointers, and then use new, like this:

```
std::thread * thread[N_THREADS];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    threads[i] = new std::thread(std::bind(&Population::populationMove, &pop, (i * NumberOfPlayers / NUM_THREADS)));
}
```

Next, thread.join is a method:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        if(threads[i].joinable())
            threads[i].join();
        //std::cerr << "In Thread " << i << "\n";
    }
```

You are missing () in two places in that code.

Comment: Thanks, havent seen those braces for 2hours, haha